# Add users not showing in Jelly Bean 4.2 on TF300

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, asus-eee-pad-transformer, multi-user

I have a Asus T300. After upgrading to 4.2 I added 3 users for my children. I need to add one more. At my owner account it is not showing add users any more. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Users screen in the settings menu?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything about Jelly Bean having a maximum number of user accounts within stock Android, but it's possible that the manufacturer has imposed such a limit.

Comment: From what I can tell it's 8 users. [This new Multiple user set up allows Android tablet owners create up to eight separate accounts for friends, family members or significant others, all on a single tablet like the Nexus 7 or Nexus 10.](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/11/16/how-to-use-multiple-users-in-android-4-2-jelly-bean/)

Comment: IT is in Norwegian. But the only thing I miss is add users on the topp right side. It was ther when I add the 3 other users I have add. I have 1 owner and 3 other users now.

Comment: I have the same problem in an Asus 176c. I added an extra user and now i cannot add anymore. The link is greyed out. In an exact same machine belonging to my aunt, i can still add users.